# How to solve for the 'Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Tree' in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am fairly new to Swift and programming in general and my goal is to get better with it by doing leetcode or hackerrank problems every day or so. I'm stuck on this problem about finding the 'Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Tree' and would like to understand how to do it in Swift. I've read other links on how to do it in Java, and Python, but I don't seem to fully grasp the solution only because it's not in those languages. I tried to Google the solution specifically in Swift and I came up empty.

I've read these links here:

-- the basics of binary trees in Swift: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure

-- link to problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree/

-- someone actually made the solution here, but I'm having trouble understanding how it works: https://github.com/wty21cn/leetcode-swift/blob/master/leetcode-swift/Easy/q235-lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-search-tree.swift

I tried to tweak Solution 2 from the gitHub link but it's not working for me.

Thank you for your time. Although the solution is already posted I want to understand why it is written this way and what can be done to make it more efficient.

```
class TreeNode<T> {
    var val: T
    var left: Int
    var right: Int

    init(val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }

    func lowestCommonAncestor(_ root: TreeNode, _ p: TreeNode, _ q: TreeNode) -> TreeNode {
        var node: TreeNode? = root
        var val: T


        while node != nil {
            if node!.val < p.val && node!.val < q.val {
                node = node!.right
            } else if node!.val > p.val && node!.val > q.val {
                node = node!.left
            } else {
                return node!
            }
        }
        return node!
    }
}
```

example input:

```
let  root = [3,5,1,6,2,0,8,nil,nil,7,4]
let p = 5, q = 1
```

Comment: Solution 2 is for a *Binary Search Tree*.  The leetcode problem is for a *binary tree*.  They aren't the same thing.  A *binary tree* doesn't have any specific order.  A *Binary Search Tree* is an ordered tree in which all values to the left of a node are less than the value at that node, and all values to the right of the node are greater.  So Solution 2 won't work for the general binary tree problem that leetcode presents.

Comment: Here's how I would approach it.  Take your two values and find out which is lower on the tree.  Find the parent of the lower node, and repeat until you are on the same level.  If you're at the same node, you're done.  If not, find the parents of those two nodes and repeat.

Comment: On second thought, that would work better for trees represented with arrays because it is easy to get your parent.  For the data structure presented in leetcode, the links proceed in a downward direction, so finding your parent isn't as easy.